# Watch for changes to calendar, when to make request

Tags: react-native, google-api, google-calendar-api

When watching for changes to a collection of events on a given calendar, how often do I need to make a watch request?

Where would I put my code to make a watch request? Does it only need to be done once?

My code below gets an access token and makes a post to create a watch channel, however I'm not sure where to host the code or how often I need to run it:

```
let { google } = require("googleapis");
let functions = require("firebase-functions");
let privatekey = require("./config.json");
let axios = require("axios");

let jwt = new google.auth.JWT(
    privatekey.client_email,
    null,
    privatekey.private_key,
    ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]
);

const token = await jwt.authorize();

let headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    Authorization: token.token_type + " " + token.access_token
};
let data = {
    id: randomId,
    type: "web_hook",
    address: "https://rguc-calendars.firebaseapp.com/notifications",
    params: {
        ttl: 3600
    }
};

axios
    .post(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/thirdyear@rguc.co.uk/events/watch",
        data,
        { headers }
    )
    .then(function(response) {
        // success
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        // error
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[push notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push)

> The Google Calendar API provides push notifications that let you watch
>   for changes to resources. You can use this feature to improve the
>   performance of your application. It allows you to eliminate the extra
>   network and compute costs involved with polling resources to determine
>   if they have changed. Whenever a watched resource changes, the Google
>   Calendar API notifies your application.
>
> - Register the domain of your receiving URL.
> - For example, if you plan to use https://example.com/notifications as your receiving URL, you need to register https://example.com.
> - Set up your receiving URL, or "Webhook" callback receiver.
> - This is an HTTPS server that handles the API notification messages that are triggered when a resource changes.
> - Set up a notification channel for each resource endpoint you want to watch.
> - A channel specifies routing information for notification messages. As part of the channel setup, you identify the specific URL where you want to receive notifications. Whenever a channel's resource changes, the Google Calendar API sends a notification message as a POST request to that URL.

Once you have set up the watch google will notify you when ever there is a change you wont have to call it again.